# Detect a signal on USB without specific hardware?

Tags: usb

Is there ANY WAY to detect a signal on a USB port without a device attached? Thus just a Voltage sent to the port on the pins?

Just want to detect if a electric flow is closed? This is for a flag only, if a gate is closed (or door or something) there is a bridge in the current flow and thus sends a voltage to the USB device so that i can pick this signal up and simply then code something to notify me that the door is closed.

Is it even possible to sniff on a USB port that does not have a device connected to it?

Comment: In cases like these, it would greatly help if you explain what you want to do and why you need it.

Comment: I would like to simply pic up a signal, This is for a flag only, if a gate is closed (or door or something) there is a bridge in the current flow and thus sends a voltage to the USB device so that i can pick this signal up and simply then code something to notify me that the door is closed. Does this make more sense. The simpelist thing. Just sending the +-5V or what ever current to the port with no other hardware needed for this?

Comment: Hope this explanation makes sense. It is really just recognizing that there is a current on the port. or no current on the port.

Comment: Is it even possible to sniff on a USB port that does not have a device connected to it?

Comment: I wonder if one could somehow detect the USB being used for charging. But then, such would probably be too slow to not miss short signals. If you're into electronics, see also [electronics.stackexchange.com](http://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/72213/how-can-i-check-input-of-usb).

Comment: @Arjan even detecting charging requires some programming on a chip inside the usb device.

Comment: Ah, @LPChip, I vaguely remembered that some pull-up resistor made USB ports (*providing* the charge) increase their voltage or maximum current. But thinking about it, it's probably the other way around (the device that is being charged, somehow recognizing the resistor and acting on that). And any way, all of that might indeed not be known to the OS, or not easily queried by some software, if it is even an instant signal to start with.

Comment: Wondering if a computer can detect things like [USB fans](http://www.walmart.com/c/kp/usb-fans), @LPChip.

Comment: @Arjan, no. a computer won't detect an USB fan. It simply draws power from the power a USB gives, but there is no checking done. It is up to the device to communicate with the computer about how it uses the usb device, so that if there's insufficient power, the computer can notify the user.

Answer (score 1):

> Is it even possible to sniff on a USB port that does not have a device connected to it?

I believe the short answer is "No" (or, at least, not very easily or safely). If you are into hardware hacking though, and don't mind spending a little bit of money, something like a [USB Trigger](http://sensoriumembedded.com/productpages/usbtrigger/index.htm) is probably what you are looking for. A simple circuit to detect current flow shouldn't be too hard to attach.

Comment: I know it's just an example, but that USB Trigger is a hefty $63.00. As an alternative one might use the switches of some cheap USB joystick, or some parallel-to-USB adapter like LPChip and Tonny suggested too. Or for those who don't mind some programming, the $63.00 might be better spent on a board like [the $40 Raspberry Pi B+](http://www.raspberrypi.org/documentation/usage/gpio/README.md), which also has ethernet so doesn't need a computer to operate. (But which might become more expensive if one really wants a case, or does not have a USB charger lying around.)

Comment: Arjan et al. make great suggestions. The USB Trigger above (though pricey) was suggested to help potentially ease any learning curve. For instance, the excellent Pi B+ says "Inputs are a bit trickier [..][a]lthough it might seem reasonable just to connect a button across an input pin and a ground pin, the Pi can get confused as to whether the button is on or off. [...] This is why you will see phrases like "pull up" [...] in Raspberry Pi GPIO tutorials." The USB Trigger has "Pull-up resistors to keep inputs high when switches are off/disconnected." Thus, it could be easier for beginners.

Answer (score 1):

USB itself requires proper driver handling before you can do anything with it. Parallel and serial cables however do not. They do allow you to check for actual bits set or unset as you describe.

The reason why USB doesn't is because USB (or Universal serial bus) is a technique used to make many devices connect through one connection. There is a bit of identification going on before the device is usable in windows, and its this part (with drivers) that'll be making things hard. You'll need to have a chip on the USB with programming on it to interact with the driver on the pc. None of this is necessary through a printer or com port. There are `usb 2 com` and `usb 2 parallel` adapters available.

Comment: By far the easiest method is to use a parallel port and hook up the printer busy or paper-out pins to the circuit to monitor. (With proper electrical safeguards to prevent blowing up the port of course.) If the computer doesn't have a parallel port a USB2parallel adapter can serve the same purpose.